# How to force scripts to load before interpreting html in Rails Capybara JS tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

In my file `dances.html.erb`, my test complains:

```
Failures:

  1) Creating dances creates a new dance with non-javascript data
     Failure/Error: visit '/dances/new'

     Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
       One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

       ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
       ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
           at http://127.0.0.1:33842/dances/new:81 in global code
```

I think the offending html code looks like

```
<script>

  $( "#choreographer-autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: <%= a_to_safe_str(Choreographer.all.map &:name) %>,
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 0
  });
  $( "#start-type-autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: ["improper","Becket","Becket ccw","four face four","square dance","indecent"],
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 0
  });
</script>
```

and the offending calls to '$' are here. 
I think this means JQuery isn't loading?
If I snip them, then the next error is:

```
 Failure/Error: JSON.parse self.figures_json

 ActionView::Template::Error:
   784: unexpected token at '{{toJson(figures.arr)}}'
```

Those handlebars are an Angular thing. 
Is Angular also not loading?

Here's my Rails application.js:

```
//= require angular
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require angucomplete-alt
```

This works fine in the Real World, just not in this test.

Is there something I need to do to get these JS libs to load before the body html is executed?

Comment: What version of phantomjs are you running, and when you say it works in the real world do you mean in the dev environment or in production too?

Comment: dev environment. I haven't tried on production.
phantomjs (2.1.1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running the latest PhantomJS the most likely cause is that you have an error in one of your JS files.  A big difference between the dev and test environments is that in the test environment rails concatenates all your JS files together.  This means that an error in one file can prevent the rest of the JS from being processed.  In dev mode they're all separate so an error in one doesn't stop the others from being processed.  Check your browsers console log for errors and make sure they are fixed.

Comment: phantomjs (2.1.1.0)

Comment: @DaveMorse  Updated the answer since you are already running 2.1.1

Comment: The scripts run without js errors. 
I have another branch where a variation of this file runs under JS test, complete with calls to $() and use of {{}}, and that branch runs fine. Frustrating, but at least I'm sure I broke the thing.